# How to execute a function from a separate folder

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp

I have a project that has several folders at the top-level, with more folders in each one. I have a file in the folder Services/src/com/..., and within it I need to call a function from QAC/src/com/... The problem, of course, is that the package for the second file starts at com., so the first file can't recognize it from an import.

I'm not sure if this is even possible, and if not I'll look for another way. An alternative, if this isn't possible, is to use the function in the JSP file in the QAC folder, but I've tried that and it doesn't do what I'm going for.

I put this in the JSP file

```
document.getElementById("agentProfileForm").action = "${retrieveAgentProfile}";
window.location.reload(true);
```

which I hoped would call the function and then refresh the page. It does refresh the page, but doesn't update correctly.

I'm trying to run:

```
@RequestMapping(params = "action=retrieveAgentProfile") 
    public void handleRetrieveAgentProfile(final @ModelAttribute("agentProfileForm") AgentProfileForm agentProfileForm,
                                    final SessionStatus status, 
                                    final ActionResponse response,
                                    final ActionRequest request,
                                    final ModelMap model) { 
//Code goes here
}
```

I'm new to both the project and Spring, so there might be an obvious way to do this.

While debugging, the code enters the function I'm trying to call while loading the form, so I'm trying to update it again by using the same function. Simply refreshing the page doesn't update it to the new data that is added to the database after initially loading the form, although the database does in fact update, which is evident if I leave the form and then re-enter it in the same way that uses the function.

Comment: do you mean a completely different project

Comment: It's the same project, just a different part of it. It's a very big project.
I know that it's possible to access files in the Services folder from the QAC folder, because the java for the functionality I'm adding is in the Services folder, but it's accessed by jQuery.getJSON in the JSP file, which is in the separate folder.

Comment: if it is a different compilation unit you will need to build it and then have it available as a dependency and then just import it as normal. if same unit then should just be able to import.

Comment: @mavriksc I edited my original comment. Like I say, I've done it before, I'm just new to Spring and don't fully understand RequestMapping.